# MySQL Update column with case on joined tables not working

Tags: mysql, join, case

At first, I created a table 'customers'. Then I updated 'customers' with one more attribute 'cust_level'. I have another table 'orders'. Now, I want to update the cust_level on 'customers' table on the basis of the 'quantity' ordered in 'orders' table. But when I tried to update the table 'Customers', I am getting the following error:

> 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 10  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Thanks for any help!

```
create table customers(
    customer_id    varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);

ALTER TABLE customers ADD cust_level CHAR(1);

create table orders(
    order_id    int,
    order_no        varchar(10),
    quantity    int,
    order_date      date,
    delivery_date   date,
    customer_id    varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
);

update  customers C
left join
    (
        select customer_id,sum(quantity) as total_purchase from orders group by customer_id
    ) A on C.customer_id=A.customer_id
set C.cust_level =  case
        when A.total_purchase>2  then C.cust_level='3'
        when A.total_purchase>0 and A.total_purchase<3 then C.cust_level='2'
        else C.cust_level='1'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET C.cust_level = CASE
    WHEN A.total_purchase>2 THEN C.cust_level='3'
    WHEN A.total_purchase>0 AND A.total_purchase<3 THEN >C.cust_level='2'
    ELSE C.cust_level='1'
END
```

This CASE expression has an issue. You are designating which column should be updated before the CASE (SET C.cust_level = ...) but referring to them inside the CASE (... THEN C.cust_level='3'). The CASE should return a single value, that will be assigned to the designated column.

This should be written :

```
SET C.cust_level = CASE
    WHEN A.total_purchase > 2 THEN '3'
    WHEN A.total_purchase > 0 AND A.total_purchase < 3 THEN '2'
    ELSE '1'
END
```

Finally : WHEN conditions are evaluated one after the other, and CASE stops on the first match. So while functionality equivalent, this could be simplified as :

```
SET C.cust_level = CASE
    WHEN A.total_purchase > 2 THEN '3'
    WHEN A.total_purchase > 0 THEN '2'
    ELSE '1'
END
```

Comment: Honestly, I had spent some fair amount of time on this. I understood the problem now finally. It worked. Thank you so much. I really liked your explanation on the WHEN condition. Appreciate it.

Comment: I like the last bit of the answer best

Comment: @scaisEdge : ahh yes, you are correct, thanks for your comment. It's fixed.